# Angular UI Bootstrap $scope.$modalInstance.close causes: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined

Tags: jquery, angularjs, angular-ui

I have a few modals, 2 are working perfectly, 1 is getting this exception when closing.
(It does manage to close the modal, but angular logs out this exception).

I've looked closer and, the `$modalInstance` is defined inside the `close` method, but `openedWindows.get($modalInstance)` returns `undefined`.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Can you create a Fiddle?

Comment: I'm getting this, too. First close is successful, second has this error. Investigating.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This is a bug in $modal in v0.10.0. See [this github issue](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/issues/1643), and will be fixed in the next release.

[@IvanZh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3401897/ivanzh) has provided answer for a similar question here - [Dismiss angular modal on URL change - errors in console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22286457/dismiss-angular-modal-on-url-change-errors-in-console)

In you controller, once you do $modal.open, add a finally block where you explicitly set the modalInstance to null. plunkr for dismiss modal on URL change is available in the above question. Yours should be very similar.

```
$scope.modalInstance = $modal.open({
    templateUrl: 'add.html',
    controller: 'AddCtrl'
  });
  $scope.modalInstance.result.then(function() {
    console.log('Success');
  }, function() {
    console.log('Cancelled');
  })['finally'](function(){
    $scope.modalInstance = undefined  // <--- This fixes
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also get this error if you try to close the $modal immediately. I ran into this when I accidentally forgot to include a delay argument in my call to $timeout. Here is the bad code:

```
var modal = $modal.open({
  templateUrl: 'static/partials/simple.dialog.html',
  controller: function($scope) {
    $scope.opts = opts;
  }
});

$timeout(function() {
  simple.close();
});
```

This was fixed by adding the timeout:

```
$timeout(function() {
    simple.close();
}, opts.timeout);
```

Answer (score 1):

$The documentation (https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/) says :
In addition the scope associated with modal's content is augmented with 2 methods:

$close(result)

$dismiss(reason).

The javascript though doesn't tally with this and injecting a $modalInstance doesn't work.
This worked for me:

```
app.controller('myController', [ '$scope', 
function ( $scope) {
..

 $scope.addClient = function () {
   $scope.$close(); // or $scope.$dismiss();
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This method didn't work well for me.

I too had 'value' undefined messages, from a series of dialogs based on the state of application. One dialog was a spinning icon "Your request is Processing", that was closed in the parent scope once an $http request resolved.

But it wouldn't close using this and the aforementioned result.then:

```
if ($scope.modalInstance) {
     $scope.modalInstance.dismiss();
}

...

$scope.modalInstance.result.then(function() {
    console.log('Success');
  }, function() {
    console.log('Cancelled');
  })['finally'](function(){
    $scope.modalInstance = undefined;
  });
```

Everything began to work when I switched to:

```
$scope.modalInstance.result.then(function() {
        ...
       $scope.modalInstance = undefined;
}, function() {
       ...
       $scope.modalInstance = undefined;
});
```

Maybe the error was that $scope.modalInstance was set to undefined without ever closing/dismissing the original instance.